# Device lose root access after installing SU .zip update from stock recovery

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, root-access, recovery-mode, superuser

I rooted my device, Samsung Galaxy S3, by connecting my device to pc via usb, and one-click-root with *KingROOT* application(on my pc). It automatically install a superuser on my device, but it's not the *SuperSU* that developed by Chainfire, instead, it's called *Kingo Superuser*. It works fine, but unfortunately an app did not get authorize by Kingo Superuser, it keep asking for authorization from SuperSU.
I don't know why SuperSU is asking for update even though I just install it from Play Store. Since I don't have a custom ROM, I choose *Normal* when asking for update method. Before I do that, I already install the *.zip* update file from recovery. (I saw 3 red lines, *...can't get signature..., something like that when I install it.*) After it completed, device starts to reboot. The worst thing is after rebooting, my device lose root access :( 
I searched for solution online about updating SuperSU and related stuff but I can't find a clear solution. So I came here, how do I update SU binary in a proper way, without a custom ROM.
Thanks.

Comment: Use Rashr or Flashify app to write a custom Recovery on the device. After that installing or removing actual SuperSU is very easy. You just flash a file and that's it.

Answer (score 0):

SuperSU zip is an unsigned zip and can only be flagged through a custom recovery like cwm our twrp. You can search on xda for a custom recovery for your device. Use Kingroot to root your device again, use fastboot or ODIN from PC (refer to XDA  for proper device-specific instructions) or Flashify to flash a custom recovery image, then full unroot from Kinguser, and then flash the SuperSu zip from custom recovery.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138091/discussion-on-answer-by-tamoghna-chowdhury-device-lose-root-access-after-install).